# Binding an ImageView with a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, adapter

I had followed [the tutorial about the GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). I am trying to bind an ImageView with a GridView from a layout xml file via an Adapter. I captured the ImageView from the mainActivity and I tried both ways by entering the ImageView through the constructor of the ImageAdapter or by making the ImageView static. Both of them return a Runtime Exception.

```
    //capturing imageView in the mainActivity

        public static ImageView IMAGE_VIEW;
            IMAGE_VIEW=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
 public int getCount() {
        // It should return 16 ImageViews
        return 16;
    }
.
.
.

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(20, 20, 4, 4);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }


              imageView=MainActivity.IMAGE_VIEW; //I suppose here is the problem

     // the code underneath works fine for an Image File not for the ImageView     
    // imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.crazy);


            return imageView;
        }
}
```

What is the error here? What would be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below tutorials for custom gridview

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

you will more ideas about gridview...

Comment: Thanks, I have found the solution in the second link. I had to call LayoutInflater.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do like this.
In your main xml file:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</GridView>
```

In your xml file which describes grid item:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</TextView>
```

Adapter:

```
 // references to our images
public int[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.icon_1,
        R.drawable.icon_2,
        R.drawable.icon_3,
        R.drawable.icon_4,
        R.drawable.icon_5,
        R.drawable.icon_6
};
```

in method getView:

```
TextView item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    item.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

in Activity:

```
// set grid menu
GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(); //put here your arguments
gridview.setAdapter(leftMenuAdapter);
```